# Игра на Unity зависает, не выкидывая при этом никаких ошибок

Tags: c#, unity3d

Изначально игра зависала еще от перенасыщения делегатами. Эту проблему я исправил, теперь зависает только при определенном действии, логично, что проблема должна быть в нем, но код работает без ошибок и проблема появляется не всегда, с разными интервалами по времени.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие могут быть причины подобного зависания (бесконечного цикла или рекурсии в проекте нет), встречались ли вы с подобным и как решали?

Comment: такая проблема в готовом билде или в редакторе?

Comment: В обоих случаях

Comment: Попробуйте часть вещей в игре отключить и посмотреть пропали ли тормоза. Если пропали, верните часть, если нет, отключите еще часть. Так вы найдете хотя бы то место где проблема. Когда найдете покажите код который вызывает зависание.

Comment: Также можно профайлером посмотреть почему лагает, но если зависло насовсем, то это не поможет.

Comment: Именно, что зависает на совсем, профайлер не помогает.
По поводу отключения части вещей этим сейчас и занимаюсь. Думал, возможно, кто то уже сталкивался с подобным

Comment: Обычно "зависания насовсем" это признак бесконечного цикла. Любой цикл с условиями может стать бесконечным, если с условием пойдет что-то не так...
Наверняка у Вас есть в коде циклы. Поставьте какие-нибудь маркеры "Debug.Log("Имя цикла")" на входе и выходе из циклов. И попробуйте поймать зависание снова

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский согласен насчет цикла, но насчет логов сомневаюсь, что это поможет, ведь если программа зависнет, до отрисовки окна консоли с надписями дело и не дойдет.

Comment: Если бы был бесконечный цикл, то проблема повторялась бы при одних и тех же действиях. А здесь время до зависания каждый раз разное

Comment: Действия, приводящие к ошибке, необязательно должны быть одинаковыми. Так что вполне может быть и цикл, просто иногда программа в него входит а иногда нет

Comment: Нет, дело не в этом. Нет ни бесконечных циклов, ни рекурсий. К слову игра мультиплеерная, работает через Photon

Comment: Я опять за старое. Какая-нибудь синхронизация с сервером имеется? Она реализована с цикле или корутине?
В любом случае, Вам и только Вам виднее, где узкие места в коде, которые могут гипотетически привести к зависанию.

Comment: Я бы хотел взглянуть на скрипт. На тот скрипт который по вашему и создаёт причину зависания.

Comment: Не понятно, что является причиной, есть скрипт, который реализует "убийство", персонажа, но там ничего интересного, что могло бы вызвать проблемы. Да и зависает не сразу, а иногда не зависает вообще. Можем в лс пообщаться, я дам больше информации, уже неделю бьюсь с этой проблемой